# App Validation on Xcode 6 GM release

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, xcode6gm

When I try to validate my build using xcode 6 GM release I am getting this error. 
Error : itunes store operation failed no eligible software found. Make sure this software is owned by your developer organization.

Can anybody here suggest some solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using application loader. I had the same issue with Xcode and using the loader worked for me.

Comment: Does application loader also Validate the App?

Comment: Application Loader uploaded my app but in iTunesConnect, it doesn't let me Submit for Review.. weird..

Comment: use Application loader 2.9

Comment: @VanDuTran try hitting the save button first and then try submit for review

Comment: A key thing here is that you should use your iTunes Connect AppleID with the Application Loader. This may be different from the AppleID whose certificate you used to sign the app.

Answer (score 37):

Probably you're using a different AppleID for iTunes Connect than for Developer Portal. You can use such a workaround:

Export archive in Organizer (Save for iOS App Store Deployment) and then use Application Loader (Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader) to upload it to iTunes Connect. It allows you to input credentials

Comment: This was precisely my problem - thanks for sharing this answer and for the explanation of how to export so that Application Loader could do the submission.

Comment: Thanks, never would have figured this out!  Frustrating...this latest release of Xcode 6 and iOS8 has been pretty rough.

Comment: This worked for me. Previously I was using my personal Apple ID in XCode, which was part of a team managed by a different Apple ID. It used to work OK providing the team was selected in XCode. But now it seems I have to add the other Apple ID (the team admin) to XCode and select the SAME team nested under that account in order for validation to succeed. More un-documented changes, thanks Apple!

Comment: Thank you! I never would have figured this out either. It's so dumb and annoying that Apple lets us use the same email with multiple developer programs but not with multiple iTunes Connect accounts.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and it resolved by making sure it logged in with the correct account.

When the modal dialog asks to select a "Development Team to use for provisioning"
Choose "View Accounts..." make sure the correct account shows in the "Apple IDs" list.

If the Apple ID is not there, use the plus sign to add a new Apple ID account.
Close the Accounts screen.

On the "Development Team to use for provisioning" use the drop down to select the account you just added, select Choose and then Validate and it will work.

Comment: Damnit this is going to be a real problem. Our developer ID is used for multiple clients, but due to limitations on iTunes Connect we have to use a different Apple ID for each client.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too and as some commenters point out, the reason was the different Apple ID used on itunesconnect vs. xCode.

I was able to solve it on xCode adding my itunesconnect Apple ID on xCode preferences and making sure it is selected during validation. The right team was not enough for me, it has to be the right team on right account.

Comment: Absolutely the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend ensuring that the account in question has been invited as both the apple developer and iTunesConnect account. This should resolve the problem. You may have to go into Preference in Xcode and re-add the account.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me with many projects , so just try to re choose your **provisioning profile** and **code signing identity** in the build settings for your project

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xcode6. Xcode6.1 GM seed's iOS SDK version is now beta 8.1. You can't submit a beta binary to iTunes Store.